# Using Standard SQL, how do I make a report with a top title?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using Standard SQL, how do I make a report with a top title?

Last year I participated in a Database competition. The description said I could use MySQL, Oracle, or MS SQL Server. I choose MySQL because that is what I am familiar with. It said that I must write an sql statement using Standard SQL that will work in any of the listed DBMS. I have searched google, but no luck on finding any tutorials or anything related to the issues below. Any suggestions on where to look or what to search would be great.

1. Group by and perform a control break on the plan ID (skip one line
   after the break).
2. Insert a top title and bottom title as shown.
3. Set your page size to
   30, and the width of the line to 65.
4. Column 1 has a width of 10, Column 2 has a width of 15, Column 3 has
   a width of 15, and Column 4 has a width of 20.

The expected formatted report is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... those requirements are terrible.  Sql isn't meant for laying out reports, and this competition is teaching people the wrong approach.  This is the equivalent of having a Javascript contest where the objective is to write Sql queries client-side...

Comment: I have heard there are report generators for MS Access DB and I personally use PHPMyAdmin to just get generic results then format with PHP and CSS. I didn't know you could even do the things these requirements call for. Any ideas where to start learning about a reporting feature of MySQL or the other DBMS?

Comment: @zechdcThe requirement of creating a Standard SQL query that will produce these results seems to exclude the use of any of the normal reporting tools that you would use for solving this type of problem.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson That is what I thought. I can't use any standard system like PHPMyAdmin or a report generator. I am sure there is a way to do this using Standard SQL, otherwise they wouldn't have made it 50% of the competition requirements. Any ideas where to start searching?

Comment: The settings for formatting don't belong to any Standard SQL query. They look like a part of a command line querying tool. Do you have a set of data to work on?

Comment: @zechdc I think you could potentially create a `SELECT` statement that would return those results... but it would be one of the ugliest `SELECT` statements ever written... which is why people normally don't use SQL for this type of thing...

Comment: @Marian Unfortunately, no, I don't have a dataset. I have an ERD for the whole system. Would that help?

Comment: @zechdc: Give my outline below a try; I will keep an eye on this Q in case you run into any roadblocks. You will learn much more by building it mostly yourself than by being presented with 'some of the ugliest SQL you have ever seen'.

Comment: Well, to anyone trying to help with the query, yes, that would be helpful. But I'm not sure anyone would be able to help with the formatting. That might be too ugly doing pure SQL :-).

Comment: I can think of a way of doing that (at least partially) with standard SQL - just not with MySQL

Comment: So it looks like this was created using something like SQL*Plus. Does SQL*Plus work across MySQL, Oracle, and MS SQL Server? After looking at the SQL*Plus documentation, looks like it has commands for titles, breaks, width, etc. However, it looks like SQL*Plus is for Oracle only. Am I incorrect in saying that? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going through cleaning up old questions. For anyone who might be curious, I actually used PL/SQL for the competition. Worked great for creating "reports" directly in SQL. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The comments above to the question not withstanding, 18 months ago I had to build 2 queries similar to this for a real-world reporting application. The requirements were unusual, and for an unusual reporting environment, but none-the-less were quite sane and sensible. The end-product of the query was then spun into MS-Access for final reporting and printing. It was quite fun to program actually.

Using SQL Server, the SQL dialect I am most familiar with, the report can be built as follows.

Note that of the 30 lines for the report outlined 20 are data rows, and 10 are page header, columns header, or page footer rows.

1. Build a query for the main data grouped on Plan Id that outputs each field converted to a varchar of the requisite length.
2. Build a super query over (1) that generates a single 65 character text string as each row output
3. Buid a super-query that groups (2) on PlanId with a test on `grouping(PlanId)` that generates empty strings in every column;this is the blank line after each PlanId group.
4. Build a super-query over(3) that assigns a sequential RowNumber to each row, and then calculate fields `PageNumber = floor(RowNumber / 20)` and  `PageSequence = RowNumber mod 20`.
5. Manually build the header/footer rows with appropriate PageSequence values, and cross join to the distinct values of PageNumber from (4).
6. Union All (4) and (5) with an appropriate Order By clause.
7. Etc.

The actual application where I had to apply these techniques required creating an MS-Access report that had an indefinite number of pages running out horizintally, with 6 numeric columns and 1 descriptive column per page, with the final numeric column being a total of all previous numeric columns. The whole report was three of these, each starting on a new page, but each with a different number of numeric columns. Because of how the raw data was stored on the SQL Server, and the slow data link, it was much more efficient to run the whole report as one query than three separate ones.

Have fun.

**P.S.**
Because of other project constraints, I had the benefit of dynamically creating this SQL using a SQL-macro facility similar to that of old-style C; hand-rolled of course, because who ever heard of such a thing. When you can write it that way, it ALMOST looks structured.